# One-sample Wilcoxon test result does not make sense

Tags: hypothesis-testing, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, wilcoxon-signed-rank

To evaluate the correctness of a value I have given to something, I have asked a group of people to give a value for it. To evaluate the significance difference between my value with them, I am running a one sample Wilcoxon test. The reason for this choice is that the data are non-parametric and I have no assumption on data distribution. My data are discrete, from 1 to 4.
The vector of data is as following:

- 29 values are equal to 3,
- 19 values are less than 3,
- 9 values are greater than 3,
- The null hypothesis is that the value equal to 3.

The Wilcoxon test rejects the null hypothesis despite the fact that half of the values agree with it. Note that I have used a parameter in Python that is called Pratt, to not to discard the observation when the difference is zero.

**EDIT** I found out that my data has [skeweness](https://www.quality-control-plan.com/StatGuide/srank_paired_ass_viol.htm) problem. And as the test suggest I am thinking to pick the [one sample sign test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_test#Example_of_sign_test_for_median_of_a_single_sample). What I am looking for in these test is to understand the Mode not the Median. I am interested to know how many people agree with my given value---that in the given example I am my given value is 3. Should I be worry about this and look for a test for the mode (which I have never seen?)

Comment: It is usually a good starting point to formulate hypotheses about a (population) parameter. What parameter are you interested in?

Comment: I am interested in Mode, that is the most occurring number within a data distribution.

Comment: Your test results in the conclusion, that the values are not symmetric around 3. Given, that they are dicrete, their true median can still be 3. Carefully note, that the Wilcoxon-Tests are not about the median! You ask about a fix without telling, what is broken. What is so special about `mu==3` that anything else needs to be fixed?

Comment: @Bernhard Thanks for your respond (and sorry to get back late).i have edited my question.